# jQuery function not invoking on page load

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery file with function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   // Function to disable first two options of dropdowns
   function disableNG(){
        jQuery('[name=bundle_attribute_pa_maat_163] option:eq(0)').attr("disabled",true);
        jQuery('[name=bundle_attribute_pa_maat_160] option:eq(0)').attr("disabled",true);
        jQuery('[name=bundle_attribute_pa_maat_163] option:eq(1)').attr("disabled",true);
        jQuery('[name=bundle_attribute_pa_maat_160] option:eq(1)').attr("disabled",true);
    };
    disableNG();
});
```

But for some reason this function is not disabling the two first options of the dropdown on page load.

I call the function `disableNG();` on a few `.change()` functions, on which they work fine.

I don't understand why they don't disable on the initial page load.

Comment: use .prop rather than .attr, if you'e using new library of jquery versions. hope it should work

Comment: I've changed it to prop. But the weird thing is, that if I call this function on a .change() it works, but not when on initial page load. And I've called it inside a document ready function.

Comment: For select boxes, check boxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

Comment: I'm using select boxes, but that's working, each time I make a selection the .change() function is fired. &nbsp; It's just when the page initially loads I expect the disableNG() function to disable the options, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

First, use the new `ready state` syntax. Second, use `.prop` instead of `.attr`, because thats a `property` and not an `attribute` you want to set.

```
jQuery(function($){
   // Function to disable first two options of dropdowns
   function disableNG(){
        $('[name=bundle_attribute_pa_maat_163] option:eq(0)').prop("disabled",true);
        $('[name=bundle_attribute_pa_maat_160] option:eq(0)').prop("disabled",true);
        $('[name=bundle_attribute_pa_maat_163] option:eq(1)').prop("disabled",true);
        $('[name=bundle_attribute_pa_maat_160] option:eq(1)').prop("disabled",true);
    };
    disableNG();
});
```

Comment: Hello there, first of all. Thanks for the quick reply. It is because I am re using that piece of code to disable the first two options each time someone changes the option value of a dropdown.
Here's a pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/ewWavfP5

Comment: You could do your work much better. But I'm not sure, what your change events are for. But they seems to be have an issue too, maybe not the function is the issue, it's your events. But thats just an idea ... https://pastebin.com/kizXJiwz @ArneDeBelser

Comment: This is actually the first real JS (jQuery) file I'm writing to have some actions. So I'm pretty sure that my work could be much better. So I'm happy that you're wanted to help me out a little bit.

The change() functions are called on dropdown lists. So what I'm trying to achieve is that each time a a new value is selected, it makes sure that the property of the two first options stays disabled.

Comment: Also, I see that you use $ signs instead of jQuery, when I try to do this I get the following error:https://i.gyazo.com/222cbe791e874a8ce84aa0306690b3c1.png That's why i'm using jQuery

Comment: DSid you noticed the first line in my code? `jQuery(function($) {` @ArneDeBelser